# Defining same GET twice

Tags: browser, cross-browser

Is there a defined protocol as to what browsers should do in this case:

`http://example.com/?id=1&id=2`

Can I safely assume all browsers will use the same parameter, or is this not standardized? From testing it appears browsers will take the last-defined parameter (id=2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web servers usually use the *last* parameter. In your case, web servers use the second `id`.

Comment: I noticed the same, but I'd like to know if this is what they usually do, or if this is a standard behaviour I can expect for all browsers?

Comment: this issue is not related to browsers just treated by web servers. browsers just generates these query strings

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks. Do you know if there is any standard among them, or does it vary?